# mysql highcharts pie php get var value into request url

Tags: php, json, highcharts

hi guys I am a newer  I have a question about how to get var from input form into request url

```
      <!DOCTYPE HTML>
      <html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>中国武夷 000797 - 历史大单</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function() {
            var options = {
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'container',
                    plotBackgroundColor: null,
                    plotBorderWidth: null,
                    plotShadow: false,
                },
                title: {
                    text: '中国武夷 000797 历史大单 from 2016-03-14'
                },
                tooltip: {
                    formatter: function() {
                        return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ Highcharts.numberFormat(this.percentage,2) +' %';
                    }
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    pie: {
                        allowPointSelect: true,
                        cursor: 'pointer',
                        dataLabels: {
                            enabled: true,
                            color: '#000000',
                            connectorColor: '#000000',
                            formatter: function() {
                               return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ Highcharts.numberFormat(this.percentage,0) +' %';
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                series: [{
                    type: 'pie',
                    name: 'BigVolume share',
            colors: ['#DD5044','#17A05D','#FFCE43'],
                    data: []
                }]
            }
             $jsonurl="000797vol400piedata.php?df=";
             $.getJSON($jsonurl, function(json) {
                 options.series[0].data = json;
                 chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
             });

     $('#button').click(function() {
        $jsonurl="000797vol400piedata.php?df=";
        $.getJSON($jsonurl2, function(json) {
                    options.series[0].data = json;
            chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options).redraw();                   
            });
         });

            // window.setInterval(function(){
            //  $.getJSON("000797datapievol400.php", function(json) {
             //    options.series[0].data = json;
              //   chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
             // });
            //}, 3000);

        });
        </script>

       <!--  <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script> -->
    <script src="../../stock/js/highcharts.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
       <div id="container" style="min-width: 280px;  height: 230px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
        <form name="form" action="<?php $jsonurl2 = $jsonurl.$_GET['df'];?>" method="GET">
        <input type="text" name="df" value="2016-4-1" />
        <input type="button" id="button" value="Start Date" />
            </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

the 000797vol400piedata.php code is

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","tushare","tusharetushare");
$df = htmlspecialchars($_GET["df"]) ;
if (!$con) {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("stockhistory", $con);

$resultx = mysql_query("select type,sum(volume) from `vol400-000797` where type='买盘' and date BETWEEN '$df' AND current_date()");
$rowsx = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($resultx)) {
    $row[0] = $r[0];
    $row[1] = $r[1];
    array_push($rowsx,$row);
}

$resulty = mysql_query("select type,sum(volume) from `vol400-000797` where type='卖盘' and date BETWEEN '$df' AND current_date()");
$rowsy = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($resulty)) {
    $row[0] = $r[0];
    $row[1] = $r[1];
    array_push($rowsy,$row);
}

$resultz = mysql_query("select type,sum(volume) from `vol400-000797` where type='中性盘' and date BETWEEN '$df' AND current_date()");
$rowsz = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($resultz)) {
    $row[0] = $r[0];
    $row[1] = $r[1];
    array_push($rowsz,$row);
}


$rows=array_merge($rowsx,$rowsy,$rowsz);


print json_encode($rows, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

> I think there is something wrong with  form code
>   The $jsonurl2 can not get the value when I click the button

Comment: How does the output of $jsonurl2 look like? You can't use php variable in js like a normal js variable.

Comment: the jsonurl return my json fomat data

Comment: My question is how to get the input form var and put the var into the $jsonurl2

Comment: This is a mess - `<?php $jsonurl2 = $jsonurl.$_GET['df'];?>`

Comment: you are right. can you give me the correct code

Comment: Check my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Your form action must be 000797vol400piedata.php, so your form would look like:

```
<form name="form" action="000797vol400piedata.php" method="GET">
        <input type="text" name="df" id="df" value="2016-4-1" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Start Date" />
</form>
```

And in 000797vol400piedata.php

you get df value using $_GET['df']:

```
$df = $_GET['df'];
```

In your case, in order to use the PHP variable in javascript, you should consider using ajax. So your code must be:

```
    $(function () {    
        $('form').on('submit', function (e) {    
          e.preventDefault();//prevent default submit
         var df = $('#df').val();
         //other codes
         $.getJSON('000797vol400piedata.php', {
             df: df//Here we have our submitted data
          }, function(json) {
              options.series[0].data = JSON.parse(json);
              chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);    
         //other codes
         });
     });
});
```

stop using mysql extension, use PDO or mysqli.

Comment: I have test the code ,but  it is not working when I click the submit button

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at this line of your code

`<form name="form" action="<?php $jsonurl2 = $jsonurl.$_GET['df'];?>" method="GET">`

in the action attribute of the form

`action="<?php $jsonurl2 = $jsonurl.$_GET['df'];?>"`

replace it with

`action="000797vol400piedata.php"`

also inside the form, in this line

```
<input type="button" id="button" value="Start Date" />
```

change that in

```
<input type="submit" id="button" value="Start Date" />
```

and your form must look like this,

```
  <form name="form" action="000797vol400piedata.php" method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="df" value="2016-4-1" />
    <input type="submit" id="button" value="Start Date" />
  </form>
```

in your `000797vol400piedata.php` you can do like this to get the value of var you pass. this is just an example of how to receive value sent from the form. use this as an example to you code.

```
$value = $_GET['df'];
echo "$df";
```